# How to detect cell blur (out of focus) event in Ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I need to detect when the grid cell loses focus in ag grid.
I've checked the available API in the docs but didn't find anything similar to cell blur.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/
Any suggestions how to check it?

Comment: depending on your use-case, it looks like `cellMouseOut` might be doing what you are looking for

Comment: No, this type doesn't suit my needs. 'cause user can navigate to cell using the keyboard

Comment: @Ig_React please check the answers from the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61950465/ag-grid-opposite-method-to-cellfocused/61998566#61998566.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ag-grid opposite method to cellFocused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61950465/ag-grid-opposite-method-to-cellfocused)