# Ag-grid opposite method to cellFocused

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, ag-grid

folks!
Does anyone know the opposite method to `cellFocused` in ag-grid? 
I need to detect when the focused cell loses its focus and run some actions.

Thanks for your responses.

[image]

Comment: Could you keep track the last focused cell data, and then when you receive another `cellFocused` event, you know the old cell was unfocused?

Comment: @MattNienow yes, this was the first idea, but how to track if user clicks on some button from the toolbar or smth else. It's really weird that this package does not have so obvious method

Comment: related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61949782/how-to-detect-cell-blur-effect-in-ag-grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way to support `onBlur` event. Since ag-grid doesn't have a built-in method, I created wy own event listener to the focus cell node and remove it after losing the focus state.

So, my code looks like this. Inside the react class I have 3 additional methods:

```
removeCellBlurListener = () => {
    const target = document.activeElement;
    if (target) {
        target.removeEventListener('blur', this.onCellBlur);
    }
};

addCellBlurListener = () => {
    const target = document.activeElement;
    if (target) {
        target.addEventListener('blur', this.onCellBlur);
    }
};

onCellBlur = () => {
    ...do something on blur
};

render () {
    return (
        <AgGridReact
              {...restProps}
              onCellFocused={(e) => this.addCellBlurListener()}
              onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
         />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If one action you want to run is, that the cell looses it's focus you can use

```
stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus={true}
```

or another action could be

```
 onCellEditingStopped={onCellEditingStopped}
```

where

```
const onCellEditingStopped = useCallback(
    (params) => {
       ... DO SOMETHING 
    },
    []
);
```